# Consultar duas ou mais palavras em uma string

Tags: sql, postgresql, regex

Preciso fazer com que meu `select` traga apenas registros cuja descrição tenha as palavras "RACAO" e "ROYAL". Estou usando Regex para facilitar, mas não sei por que está trazendo registros que não têm nada a ver com a pesquisa.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
select * from cadpro where descricao ~ '^[RACAO ROYAL].*'
```

Comment: Porque não usar o operador ` %  ` ?     Ex.:  `select * from cadpro where descricao like '%RACAO%ROYAL%'`

Comment: Olá @Mauro Rocha! O Problema dessa abordagem é que ela só consulta se dentro de uma linha existirem as duas palavras. As linhas que contiverem uma das palavras citadas, não estão sendo trazidas. Preciso que ele traga os registros que tenham as duas palavras ou que contenham pelo menos uma das palvras.

Comment: Não sei se entendi mas será que não é `descricao ~ '^[RACAO|ROYAL].*'`?

Comment: Já tentei usar o pipeline separando as palavras, mas não muda o resultado.

Comment: Tenta assim: `'^(admin|com).*'`

Comment: @MauroRocha assim funcionou: select * from cadpro where descricao ~ '^(RACAO|ROYAL).*'. Posta a solução que eu concluo e te marco. Obrigado Pessoal!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apenas para explicar porque a sua regex não funcionou:

Os colchetes definem uma [classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), ou seja, a expressão dará *match* em qualquer um dos caracteres que estiverem entre `[` e `]`. Por exemplo, `[abc]` significa "a letra `a`, ou a letra `b`, ou a letra `c`" (**apenas uma delas**) - é uma expresão que corresponde a apenas **um** caractere.

Portanto `[RACAO ROYAL]` significa "a letra `R`, ou a letra `A`, ou a letra `C`, ou a letra `A` (de novo, por isso é redundante ter o `A` duas vezes aqui), ou a letra `O`, ou um espaço, ou a letra `R` (de novo), etc".

E como você usou o [marcador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^`, que significa "início da string", esta regex traz todos os registros que começam com qualquer um desses caracteres (por isso ela traz as colunas que começam com "C", com "R", etc).

Se você quer verificar duas opções diferentes, e essas opções tem mais de um caractere, a solução (como já sugeriu a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/468638/112052)) é usar [alternância](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html): o caractere `|`, que significa "ou". Então ficaria:

```
select * from cadpro where descricao ~ '^(RACAO|ROYAL).*';
```

Trocando os colchetes por parênteses, funciona, porque os parênteses agrupam a expressão `RACAO|ROYAL` (ou é "RACAO", ou é "ROYAL"). Dessa forma, a regex só considera os registros que começam com "RACAO" ou "ROYAL".

Sem os parênteses a expressão ficaria `^RACAO|ROYAL.*`, e devido à precedência dos operadores, ela significaria "começa com RACAO, ou tem ROYAL (em qualquer lugar, não necessariamente no começo)". Veja a diferença [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/EbLvBi/1/) e [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/EbLvBi/2/). Por isso os parênteses são necessários.

> Obs: usar `[RACAO|ROYAL]`, como foi sugerido [nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/468635/consultar-duas-ou-mais-palavras-em-uma-string-postgresql#comment883956_468635), não resolve, pois isso também vai trazer os registros que começam com `|`. Esse inclusive é um erro bem comum ao usar regex: achar que os colchetes pegam o texto inteiro, quando na verdade o que tem dentro deles é apenas uma lista de caracteres a serem considerados (ou seja, `[RACAO ROYAL]` e `[ACORYL ]` são equivalentes, pois consideram os mesmos caracteres, da mesma forma que `[RACAO|ROYAL]` e `[ACORYL|]` também são equivalentes). E dentro dos colchetes, muitos caracteres especiais, como o `|`, "perdem seus poderes" e se tornam caracteres comuns, sem nenhum significado especial.

---

Como o "R" se repete em ambas as opções, outra alternativa é:

```
select * from cadpro where descricao ~ '^R(ACAO|OYAL).*';
```

Mas como nesse caso você quer os registros que começam com "RACAO" ou começam com "ROYAL", acho que nem precisa de regex:

```
select * from cadpro where descricao like 'RACAO%' or descricao like 'ROYAL%';
```

[Veja aqui](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2898b/4) as queries acima funcionando.

---

Caso queira que a consulta seja *case insensitive* (não diferencie letras maiúsculas de minúsculas), basta trocar o operador `~` por `~*` (conforme consta na [documentação](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-TABLE)), ou trocar o `like` por `ilike`.